# Why is it not incrementing? (Constructor)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, increment, destructor

Created a class named "Fahrzeug" which contains the membervariables **p_iID** and **p_iMaxID**. Now, in main I create some objects of type "Fahrzeug". Goal is that every created object has its unique ID which im trying to achieve by incrementing 
**p_iMaxID** within the constructor. Problem, it isn't incrementing. Open to any help:)

Code:

**Fahrzeug.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Fahrzeug
{
public:
    Fahrzeug();
    Fahrzeug(std::string);
    ~Fahrzeug();

private:
    std::string p_sName;
    int p_iID;
    int p_iMaxID = 0;
    //Hochzählende Fahrzeugnummer
};
```

**Fahrzeug.cpp:**

```
#include "Fahrzeug.h"
using namespace std;

Fahrzeug::Fahrzeug()
{
    p_sName = " ";
    p_iID = p_iMaxID + 1;
    cout << "ID des erzeugten Objects: " << p_iID << ", Name des erzeugten Objects: (NIX)" << p_sName << endl;
}

Fahrzeug::Fahrzeug(std::string autoName)
{
    p_iID = p_iMaxID + 1;
    p_sName = autoName;
    cout << "ID des erzeugten Objects: " << p_iID << ", Name des erzeugten Objects: " << p_sName << endl;
}

Fahrzeug::~Fahrzeug()
{
    cout << "ID des gelöschten Objects: " << p_iID << ", Name des gelöschten Objects: " << p_sName << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "Fahrzeug.h"
using namespace std;

void vAufgabe_1()
{
    Fahrzeug auto1("Auto1");
    Fahrzeug auto2("Auto2");
    string sNameInput1, sNameInput2;
    cout << "Name fuer Auto3: " << endl;
    cin >> sNameInput1;
    Fahrzeug *auto3 = new Fahrzeug(sNameInput1);
    cout << "Name fuer auto4: " << endl;
    cin >> sNameInput2;
    Fahrzeug *auto4 = new Fahrzeug(sNameInput2);

    delete auto3;
    delete auto4;
}

int main()
{
    vAufgabe_1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn to use the constructors initialization list in preference over the ctor body.

Comment: each instance of your class has its own p_maxid. You need to make p_maxid static, this will have only one int for all instances of the class. see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your variable static:

```
static int p_iMaxID = 0;
```

so that all your object share the `p_iMaxID`. You'll also need to increment it somewhere

```
p_iMaxID++;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 Reasons it is not working

- You are not actually incrementing p_iMaxID
- Your "Fahrzeuge" are not sharing the same p_iMaxID, since it is not static